# Jetpack Compose: Animating between wrapContentSize and fillMaxSize without hardcoding specific values

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Is it possible to have expand and collapse with animation while switching the size between wrapContentSize and fillMaxSize without hardcoding specific values?
Say initially a box with wrapContentSize and then on click of the box expand the box to fillMaxSize and viceversa. I need this without a hardcoded value or minsize concept.

Tried something like below, but it is not working in both cases.

```
var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    var sizeModifier by remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            if (expanded) {
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .animateContentSize(animationSpec = tween(3000, easing = LinearEasing))
            } else {
                Modifier
                    .wrapContentSize(align = Alignment.Center)
                    .animateContentSize(animationSpec = tween(3000, easing = LinearEasing))

            }
        )
    }
    Box(
        modifier = sizeModifier
            .background(Color.Green)
            .clickable {
                expanded = !expanded
                sizeModifier = if (expanded) {
                    Modifier
                        .animateContentSize(animationSpec = tween(3000, easing = LinearEasing))
                        .fillMaxSize()
                } else {
                    Modifier.wrapContentSize().animateContentSize(
                        animationSpec = tween(
                            3000,
                            easing = LinearEasing
                        )
                    )

                }
            }


    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Testing....", modifier = Modifier
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re trying to change the Modifier inside the clickable block, which doesn’t recompose the UI. Instead, you should change the expanded state inside the clickable block, and let the Modifier be decided by the expanded state.

```
var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.Green)
        .animateContentSize(animationSpec = tween(3000, easing = LinearEasing))
        .let { if (expanded) it.fillMaxSize() else it.wrapContentSize(align = Alignment.Center) }
        .clickable {
            expanded = !expanded
        }
) {
    Text(text = "Testing....", modifier = Modifier)
}
```